# UITableViewController - TableView wider than screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uistoryboard

I'm having some problem my whole day. I'm using UITableViewController. TableView has 5 static cells. I put a label inside my cell and gave it constraints. This is my cell:
[image: Cell]

Every time when I change the screen to different version of iPhone, it gives me warning that width of this label is 600 (default in storyboard) and it goes of the screen on the right side. Why TableViewController is not setting TableView screen size? What am I missing here? Is this actually a subview of viewController and if so, how to tell proper size of tableView inside storyboard with constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Just place a table view controller into your storyboard and configure your static cells. No constraints needed for this step. For your labels you need a different set of constraints:

From your picture I'm assuming you want your label to be on the left side of your table view just like in most table view cells. In that case you don't need to expand the width like that. Just drag a label into your table view cell, place it on the left side, and a) center it vertically b) pin it to the right side of the screen as shown in the screenshot (ignore the value and make sure to uncheck constrain to margin. Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Ok that works for the left side, but I want to pin it to the right side. I want to have auto resizing label on the left and one button on the right side of the cell. When I pin the button on right side, it just goes of the screen.

Comment: For the right button just do the same but pin it on the right side. That's all that changes - no need to revise frames or anything

Comment: I added vertical constraint and I pinned it to the right edge and unchecked Constrain to margins and it goes of the screen still. Warning says: expected x=327 actual x= 552

Comment: No need for vertical constraints, just center it vertically and pin it

Comment: I did that, still goes of the screen.

Comment: I wish I could, but I have a contract on this. It is really strange. I set static cells, centered everything vertical and pinned those things as you said. Everything works great if label and button are on the left side, works perfectly. But on the right side, thing just does not work as it should.

Comment: @flipper After you make the change and seeing the warning, are you running the 'Update frames' option in IB? If it's only a warning, not an error, that may be all you're missing.

Comment: Yes, for exaple for 4 inch screen. But it is not good for 4,7 inch sreen. Everything is ok in freeform mode or infered, but on other screens - that the problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as cyril says, best option is to Use TableViewController in storyboard and set as 'static prototype'. Default is 'Dynamic'. Then you don't need to manage table view in the code.